# Oops! Google Chrome could not connect

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet, browser, dns

when I refresh the site superuser.com happens is :
[image]

I previously thought because of interference with my internet connection, after I checked the other sites, its problem was not due to internet connection.

of problems occurring, whether it's due to system error or because the repair superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly causes this problem. However, I found the **solution is to close out of all Chrome windows and tabs then relaunch**. This has happen to me many time. I have also seen it redirect me to google.com when trying go to facebook.com or superuser.com.

Comment: I also tried to open in the current superuser.com error on mozilla firefox. but the same thing happen? if you close all windows and tabs, and launched again, I did the same thing, essentially re-launch.
how about it

Comment: So relaunching worked?